# Premake (lua) pch create /Yc Visual Studio

Tags: creation, premake, pch

In the premake lua script for my solution. How do i set it to create "/Yc" the phc instead of being set to use "/Yu" on first initialisation.

I have searched the online documentation and tried other help sites. I can't find any help.

I assume it's a build option but have tried `buildoptions { "/Yc" }`

Some help would be much appritiated?

Comment: Hey! Did you Find a solution for this? I am having the same problem with Premake5 where it fails to set the pch.cpp file to create and instead sets it to use. It's quite frustrating.

Comment: Yes i will answer it below and mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set the correct path to the source file.

premake5.lua

```
pchheader "awepch.h"
pchsource "%{prj.name}/Src/awepch.cpp" // this is where the source file is located on disk
```

* Also it is mandatory that you use the correct case for the characters. If you use "pch.h" for a file name on disk that must be the file name in this section of your "premake5.lua" script

Sorry to take so long to deliver the answer :)

Comment: I solved it too. But My solution was to Hardcode the Project name instead of using %{prj.name} when specifying the pchsource. Weird Behaviour.

Comment: Glad you got it solved. Compered to C Make, Premake is simple clean and easy, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify

```
pchheader('StdAfx.h')
```

and

```
pchsource('StdAfx.cpp')
```

Comment: Thank you  for you reply. I have already put this links to the file locations in my code using `pchheader` and 'pchsource'. The issue is however, rather than set the "precompiled header" option to "Create (/Yc)" it sets it to "Use (/Yu)". On the first set up and build Premake should set this to "Create (/Yc)" and once the solution is built VS will automatically change it to "Use (/Yu)" but Premake intially sets this option to "Use (/Yu)"

Comment: I will keep looking in to it @Mihai

Answer (score 0):

For the current version of premake [v5. 0.0-beta1](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/releases/tag/v5.0.0-beta1), you must do the following in order for the precompiled header to work across all IDEs (especially for Visual Studio):

1. Put both `pch.h` and `pch.cpp` under the root directory of your project (not solution/workspace).
2. Set the exact name (not a path) of the **pch.h** to `pchheader()`.
3. Set the full path of `pch.cpp` relative to **premake5.lua** script in `pchsource()`. This is **IMPORTANT**. I don't know why, but if you do not specify the full relative path, then premake will **Use (/Yu)** (use precompiled header) to the `phc.cpp` instead of **Create (/Yc)** (create precompiled header), which results in not creating the precompiled header in **Visual Studio**.
4. Include the directory where `pch.h` and `pch.cpp` are located in `includedirs()`
5. `#include "pch.h"` **IN EVERY** **.cpp** file in your project, **IN THE FIRST LINE** of each **.cpp** file. Remember: `#include "pch.h"`, **"pch.h"** must be excactly the same as the string you set in `pchheader()` in your **premake5.lua** script.
6. If you have **.c** files, you **MUST** rename them to **.cpp** instead, otherwise Visual Studio will complain about using a precompiled header that was compiled using a c++ compiler.

I know it's overcomplicated but this is how it is.

**Example:**

```lua
project "LearnGL"
    location "Projects/LearnGL/"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"
    targetdir "builds/"
    objdir "obj/%{prj.name}_%{cfg.shortname}"

    pchheader "pch.h" --Do not use paths here. Use directly the header file name
    pchsource "Projects/LearnGL/src/pch.cpp" --Full path MUST be specified relative to the premake5.lua (this) script.

    files {
        "Projects/LearnGL/src/**.h",
        "Projects/LearnGL/src/**.hpp",
        "Projects/LearnGL/src/**.cpp"
    }

    includedirs {
        "Projects/LearnGL/src/", --This is where pch.h and pch.cpp are located.
        "Projects/LearnGL/src/external/glad/include/",
        "Projects/LearnGL/src/external/stb_image/include/",
        "External/glfw/include/",
        "External/spdlog/include/"
    }
```